# How to communicate from Activity to Fragment?

Tags: android, android-fragments, kotlin

I understand that using an `interface` is a common way to communicate from `Fragment` to `Activity`. However, what are the good practices for communicating from `Activity` to `Fragment`?

In my project, my `Activity` hosts 3 `Fragments` using a `ViewPager`. My `Activity` currently listens from a backend server and I'd like to somehow notify my 3 `Fragments` whenever I get an update from the backend server. I tried implementing the `interface` approach but it already seems like a hassle as I'm already having difficulties getting references to my 3 Fragments in my Activity as the Fragments are created in a separate class which is a subclass of `FragmentPagerAdapter`.

Is there a better / cleaner way than using `interace` for communicating from `Activity` to `Fragment`?

Comment: You can go for Common ViewModel for all your fragment and activity

Comment: try using this library https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus. This may help you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try ViewModel to communicate between fragments and this is official android documentation.
Here is the link you can read it. [Share data between fragments](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel.html#sharing)
And here is a blog to read about live data [link](https://android.jlelse.eu/communicate-between-fragments-and-activity-using-livedata-631526d6357a)

**here is example**

```
public class SharedViewModel extends ViewModel {
    private final MutableLiveData<Item> selected = new MutableLiveData<Item>();

    public void select(Item item) {
        selected.setValue(item);
    }

    public LiveData<Item> getSelected() {
        return selected;
    }
}

public class MasterFragment extends Fragment {
    private SharedViewModel model;
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        model = ViewModelProviders.of(getActivity()).get(SharedViewModel.class);
        itemSelector.setOnClickListener(item -> {
            model.select(item);
        });
    }
}

public class DetailFragment extends Fragment {
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        SharedViewModel model = ViewModelProviders.of(getActivity()).get(SharedViewModel.class);
        model.getSelected().observe(this, { item ->
           // Update the UI.
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: This is a nice approach, but could you add some relevant code to the answer as well? Links might go away, code stays...

Comment: sure just give me some time :)

Comment: sorry for the inconvenience but for now here is the link to follow it step by step [link](https://www.zoftino.com/passing-data-between-android-fragments-using-viewmodel)
Hi @tynn don't worry about the code to be removed it will be there :) at least for while

Comment: It might, for sure. But it's about the quality of your answer. It's a good answer, when you find all you need directly there. Offsite resource might change any time, so it's discouraged to have answers which are hidden behind a link.